# Speeding Past a Car

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Howard travels on a busy highway having the same rate of traffic flow in each direction. Except for Howard, the traffic is moving at the legal speed of $80~ km/h$.  In the same time that it takes Howard to pass a car going in the same direction as he is, $11$ cars go by him in the opposite direction.

By what percent is Howard exceeding the legal speed limit ?

Comment: Just to be pedantic, this is an example of a poorly written word problem.  The same "rate of traffic flow" does not mean that all the cars are even spaced on the highway, just that in aggregate there are the same number.  But, as this is a homework problem this is not an issue with the OP, but with his or her teacher or textbook.  It just bothers me when students have to "guess what the question wants" because this is the sort of thing that will get you in trouble with real world problems.

Answer (score 1):

Let Howard’s speed in km/hr be $80+x$. Now pretend that he’s stationary: the cars going in the same direction appear to him to be moving towards his rear at $x$ km/hr, while the cars going in the other direction appear to be moving to his rear at $160+x$ km/hr. On the other hand, the cars going in the other direction appear to be moving to his rear $11$ times as fast as those going in the same direction, so $160+x=11x$. Now solve for $x$ and see what percentage of $80$ it is.